# Can I get a form_multiselect() to return the values I pass in rather than indexes?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter, get

I have a `form_multiselect()` to perform a search on items with associated tags.
My form:

```
<div class="control-group">
       <?= form_label('Tags: ', 'tag', $label_attr);?>

       <div class="controls">
           <?= form_multiselect('tag[]',$tags,'','id="tag-select"');?>
       </div>
</div>
```

I fill the form then with get_tags() from my model:

```
public function get_tags() {
    $this->db->select('tag_name');
    $this->db->distinct();
    $this->db->from('offers_tags');

    $query = $this->db->get();

    $results = $query->result_array();

    $tags_arr= array();
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($results as $id => $tag_name){
        foreach ($tag_name as $name){
            $tags_arr[$i] = $name;
            ++$i;
        }
    }

    return $tags_arr;      
}
```

I loop through the associative `$results` array returned from the query. If not, the form is filled with indexes and their associated arrays, when I just want a list of tag names to click.

Upon submit, I get the data, passing that data into a larger query for results later, with the following:

```
$tag_arr = $this->input->get('tag');
```

The problem I'm having then is what the form gets is just the index of whatever tag is selected from the form. I need the actual tag as a string returned through the get. 
ex:
/../../..&tag%5B%5D=8
8 being the index of what tag I selected, rather I need the tag.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

**testing update:
Still no solution to get the correct data. But I tried passing just the `results_array()` from the query into the `form_multiselect()` and what was then obtained after selecting an item, the get pulled just the value 'tag_name'. So i assume it's then passing the name of the tuple that the query pulled from because it is an associative array.

Also tried looping through the results to pass a new array form the `results_array()` with the loop:

```
foreach ($results as $id => $tag_name){
   $tags_arr[$id] = $tag_name;
}
```

So still looking to get the string data from the form. I can get the name of the tuple and the index of the string data.

I was not able to find information of using the `array_values()` function. So i tried this to no avail, still having the 'submit' return index values from the multiselect, finishing my `get_tags()` function with:

```
$tags_final = array_values($tags_arr);
return $tags_final;
```

Still searching for an answer, please help or bump this at least, it's been weeks.

Answer (score 0):

For individuals who encounter the same problem:

The following for loop performed on the resultant query did the trick!

```
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $tags = array();

    foreach($query->result() as $row)
    {
         $tags[$row->tag_id] = $row->tag_name;
    }
    return $tags;
```